# search parameters in React Router 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having issues with `react-router@6` when implementing search parameters.

To begin with, the app can search using the search form (for example, if the user searches `dark`, the app would direct to `localhost:3000/search?query=dark` to display the results),
can also use the URL in the search bar to be directed to the right page and results (for example, if the user use the URL `localhost:3000/search?query=dark`, it will direct to the page and display the results). Now, the issue is when the user types in the search form, it changes the URL by adding search parameters instantly. I am aware that this is caused by the `setSearchParams()` in the `handleChange` function, but is there any way around this to ***NOT*** change the URL when typing in the search form?

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import create from 'zustand'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faTriangleExclamation } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

// Zustand
let store = (set) => ({
  // input: '',
  // setInput: (value) => set({ input: value }),
  allImages: [],
  setAllImages: (images) => set({ allImages: images}),
  totalResults: null,
  setTotalResults: (num) => set({ totalResults: num}),
})
export const useMain = create(store)

function Header() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false)
  const [fadeOut, setFadeOut] = useState(false)
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams()
  const query = searchParams.get('query') || ''
  const allImages = useMain(state => state.allImages)
  const setAllImages = useMain(state => state.setAllImages)
  // const totalResults = useMain(state => state.totalResults)
  const setTotalResults = useMain(state => state.setTotalResults)

  function handleChange(event) {
    // setInput(event.target.value)
    setSearchParams({query: event.target.value})
  }

  async function fetchImages() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?&page=${page}&per_page=30&query=${query}&client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_API_KEY}`)
      const data = await res.json()
      if (data.total !== 0) {
        setAllImages(data.results)
        setTotalResults(data.total)
      }
    } catch(error) {
      setError(error)
    }
  }

  let navigate = useNavigate()
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    fetchImages()
    navigate(`/search?query=${query}`)
  }

  const location = useLocation()
  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname === '/search' && allImages.length === 0) {
      fetchImages()
      navigate(`/search?query=${query}`)
    }
  }, [query])

  // error
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      setShowError(true)
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFadeOut(true)
        setTimeout(() => {
          setShowError(false)
        }, 1000)
      }, 5000)
    }
  }, [error])


  return (
    <div className='header'>
      <Navbar />
      <h2 className='header--heading text-center text-light'>Find Images</h2>
      <div className='header--form'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            className='header--form--input'
            autoComplete='off'
            type='text'
            placeholder='Search'
            onChange={handleChange}
            name='input'
            value={query}
          />
        </form>
      </div>

      {showError && <div className={`network-error ${fadeOut ? 'fade-out' : ''}`}>
        <i><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTriangleExclamation} /></i>
        <div className='network-error--message'>
          <h5>Network Error</h5>
          <p>Please check your Internet connection and try again</p>
        </div>
      </div>}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

```
import './App.css';
import Main from './components/Main';
import Search from './components/pages/Search'
import Favorites from './components/pages/Favorites';
import Error from './components/pages/Error';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { SkeletonTheme } from 'react-loading-skeleton';
import { useDarkMode } from './components/Navbar';



function App() {
  const darkMode = useDarkMode(state => state.darkMode)
  let style
  if (darkMode === 'light') {
    style = 'wrapper'
  } else {
    style = 'wrapper-dark'
  }

  return (
    <div className={style}>
      <SkeletonTheme baseColor="#808080" highlightColor="#b1b1b1">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Main />} />
            <Route path='search' element={<Search />} />
            <Route path='favorites' element={<Favorites />} />
            <Route path='*' element={<Error />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </SkeletonTheme>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: ***When*** do you want the URL query params to be updated? When the form is submitted?

Comment: As I have already stated above, it is updated when it is navigated to the Search Route. So, yes, when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you ***don't*** want to update the `query` queryString parameter in real-time as the form field is being updated, but sometime later, like when the form is submitted. Keep in mind that the `setSearchParams` function works just like the `navigate` function, but operates on the queryString.

You can manually update the `searchParams` object, and when the form is submitted, call `setSearchParams` instead of `navigate`. Remove the `value` prop from the `input` element as we'll be updating the `searchParams` object.

```
function Header() {
  ...
  const location = useLocation()
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams()
  ...

  function handleChange(event) {
    searchParams.set("query", event.target.value);
  }

  ...

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetchImages();
    setSearchParams(searchParams);
  }

  ...

  return (
    <div className='header'>
      <Navbar />
      <h2 className='header--heading text-center text-light'>Find Images</h2>
      <div className='header--form'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            className='header--form--input'
            autoComplete='off'
            type='text'
            placeholder='Search'
            onChange={handleChange}
            name='input'
          />
        </form>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

[image: Edit search-parameters-in-react-router-6]